# How do I debug cli react-native bundle command further? Command hangs with no error

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I have been using appcenter.ms code deploy and the command:

`appcenter codepush release-react -a <account>/<App> -d Production`

This command hangs for eternity and never completes, here is the output:

`Loading dependency graph, done.
Loading dependency graph...info Writing bundle output to:, ./CodePush/main.jsbundle
info Done writing bundle output
info Copying 34 asset files
info Done copying assets`

Reading through their documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/cli. I tried to create the bundle myself prior to deploying, and it turns out this command is where it hangs:

`react-native bundle --platform ios --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./CodePush/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./CodePush`

Same output as above.

I have a hunch it has to do with an npm module I have added because it was working at some point recently, but I am unsure how to get more information to troubleshoot the issue further. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had installed react-native-clean-project as an npm module by mistake, once removed everything worked as expected again. Not sure exactly what the issue was because of the lack of log output.